# How is data sent to the front-end by a View function?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am required to send some data from a view-only function to the front-end. I tried using the standard approach by emitting an event with the required fields. However, when the emit call is placed within a view type function, I get an error stating the emit call is potentially state-changing and, thus, cannot be within a view function.

How is data sent to the front-end by a View function if an event cannot be used?

```js
event TestEvent (uint id);
function test() public view {
    emit TestEvent(123);
}

//Output
... TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emission of events is stored permanently on the blockchain. As such, it causes a change in state and must be placed in a non-view function.

Instead, values may be returned from view only function using `return` e.g. `return 123`